# Docker Private Registry: ping attempt failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to set up my private Docker Registry and I'm following the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/).
I have installed Docker and I'm able to run my registry on my server. But I want my registry to be more widely available. 
My docker-server with the private registry is installed on an AWS-instance.
I have created my own certificate and key by using keytool:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry \
  -v `pwd`/certs:/certs \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/certs/domain.crt \
  -e REGISTRY_HTTP_TLS_KEY=/certs/domain.key \
  registry:2
```

I'm able to ping this instance by:

```
ping ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.xx-west/east-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

But pushing is not possible:

```
The push refers to a repository [ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/ubuntu] (len: 1)
unable to ping registry endpoint https://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/v2/: dial tcp 10.x.x.x:5000: i/o timeout
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.amazonaws.com:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp 10.0.x.x:5000: i/o timeout
```

**EDIT1:** 
After changing my aws-security group. Set port 5000 to **TCP**, the error changed:

```
unable to ping registry endpoint https://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/v2/: dial tcp 10.0.x.x:5000: connection refused
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp 10.0.x.x:5000: connection refused
```

How do I have to make my registry accessible for other aws-instances?
My docker logs are showing the following. They can't find my certificate.

```
level=fatal msg="open /certs/domain.crt: no such file or directory"
```

Do I have to put this certificate in my container itself? (and generate it with keytool by myself or using an existing)

**EDIT2:** 
I've generated my own certificates using this [documentation](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/docs/insecure.md#using-self-signed-certificates).
After generating the certificates I did restart my docker daemon. I did not perform the copy of domain.crt to ca.crt because the path didn't exist. Maybe I have to create it by myself?

new error:

```
unable to ping registry endpoint https://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/v2/: dial tcp 10.0.x.x:5000: no route to host
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/v1/_ping: dial tcp 10.0.x.x:5000: no route to host
```

But I still get the following in my docker logs:

```
level=fatal msg="open /certs/domain.crt: no such file or directory"
```

After trying to perform a push, there is created a new /certs folder into my existing certsfolder

**EDIT3:** 
After finding the right directory for my certificate (/home/centos/certs/certs/*.). I get the following error:

```
level=fatal msg="open /certs/domain.crt: permission denied
```

Even if I perform a `chmod -R 777` and `chown -R root:root`

Comment: Silly question but have you opened port 5000 in your security group firewall?

Comment: Yes it's open for udp

Comment: Does `docker pull localhost:5000/image` work on the box itself? What is the output of `sudo netstat -tunlp` on the box running the registry? It is also possible you'll need to configure nginx on the registry box (there are two files mounted inside the registry container from memory) to listen for requests to your EC2 public DNS name.

Comment: @ChrisMcKinnel, pulling seems to work, the output of of that command on the container itself contains the port 5000: `tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      2515/docker-proxy `

Comment: The output changed, after I set my UDP to TCP (it's over https). I've edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You will need to place the certificate in this directory.

```
    /etc/docker/certs.d/<your-domain-name>:5000/ca.crt
```